# Groupby unique value in column, and join data in same row

Tags: pandas

I have this kind of dataframe:

[image]

I want to groupby ID and get all the next columns info into the same row, and of course in each cell like this and add more packs if there are more rows for unique values:

[image]

so far i can get all other columns in just one as list, but would like to be in proper order like second picture

```
df1 = df.groupby('ID').agg({'Grade':lambda x:list(np.r_[x])})
```

thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
df_out = (dfm := (df.set_index(['Name', 'ID', df.groupby('Name').cumcount()])
             .unstack()
             .sort_index(level=1, axis=1)))\
   .set_axis([f'{i}_{j}' for i,j in dfm.columns], axis=1)\
   .reset_index()
```

Output:

```
      Name    ID Class_0  Grade_0  Score_0 Class_1  Grade_1  Score_1 Class_2  Grade_2  Score_2 Class_3  Grade_3  Score_3
0  Gustavo  2222      LB      2.0     80.0      HD      3.0     90.0      CF      4.0     70.0     NaN      NaN      NaN
1    Maria  3333      AD      3.0     70.0      KD      4.0     70.0      LB      5.0     70.0      CF      7.0     80.0
```

Comment: columns names are not in order but I can fix that, works like a charm thank you so much